# Converting JSON reponse to an Dictonary Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I'm having some serious trouble converting my JSON response into an dictionary, just so that i can use some static data within my app in the mean time rather than having to wait for requests all the time. So the way that my JSON is formatted is like this below

**JSON REPSONSE**

```
{
    stories =     (
                {
            "Article_Link" = "http://www.webdesignernews.com/ad_redirect?id=53";
            "Article_Shares" = "";
            "Article_Time" = "";
            "Article_Title" = "35 free images: Choose from Bigstock's library of 27 million\n[ad]";
            index = 1;
            source = "Web-Designer-Depot_recent";
            url = "http://www.webdesignernews.com/";
        },
                {
            "Article_Link" = "http://www.webdesignernews.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftympanus.net%2Fcodrops%2F2015%2F09%2F14%2Fcreating-material-design-ripple-effects-svg%2F";
            "Article_Shares" = 298;
            "Article_Time" = "32 min ago";
            "Article_Title" = "Creating Material Design Ripple Effects with SVG";
            index = 2;
            source = "Web-Designer-Depot_recent";
            url = "http://www.webdesignernews.com/";
        }
    );
}
```

Here is the dictionary that i have tried to create to recreate in a playground file this response below

**Swift Dictionary**

```
var data: [String:AnyObject] [

    "stories": [

        [
            "Article_Link": "http://www.webdesignernews.com/ad_redirect?id:51",
            "Article_Shares" : "",
            "Article_Time" : "",
            "Article_Title" : "Going Retro! 150 Vintage Vector Illustrations\n[ad]",
            "index" : 1,
            "source" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ],
        [
            "Article_Link" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/redirect?url:http%3A%2F%2Fprinzhorn.github.io%2Fskrollr%2F",
            "Article_Shares" : "2.3K",
            "Article_Time" : "23 min ago",
            "Article_Title" : "Skrollr - Scroll Animations for Everyone",
            "index" : 2,
            "source" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ]
    ]  
]
```

But some of the following errors i keep getting is

Can't seem to figure out what i've done wrong here....

Comment: You forgot to add **=** to your data. **var data: [String:AnyObject] =** It should be like this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON response includes array. Your data dictionary should be like this:

```
var data: [String:AnyObject] = [

    "stories": [

        [
            "Article_Link": "http://www.webdesignernews.com/ad_redirect?id:51",
            "Article_Shares" : "",
            "Article_Time" : "",
            "Article_Title" : "Going Retro! 150 Vintage Vector Illustrations\n[ad]",
            "index" : 1,
            "source" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ],
        [
            "Article_Link" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/redirect?url:http%3A%2F%2Fprinzhorn.github.io%2Fskrollr%2F",
            "Article_Shares" : "2.3K",
            "Article_Time" : "23 min ago",
            "Article_Title" : "Skrollr - Scroll Animations for Everyone",
            "index" : 2,
            "source" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ]
    ]  
]
```

And then you can parse your dictionary such as:

```
for story in data["stories"] as! NSArray {
            println(story.valueForKey("Article_Link"))
        }
```

Comment: Hey dude, i've already parsed it using swiftyJSON i just want to create a static version of the data i've added your suggestion and also inserted the following `var data: AnyObject? = [String:AnyObject]() [......]` but i'm still getting an error

Comment: The dictionary i edited in my answer gives no error to me.

Comment: Hey dude is there anyway that i could access the data like `data["stories"][0]["Article_Title"]` rather than using a loop?

Comment: In SwiftyJson you can do that i think. But in my way, you can not access data like that. I suggest you to create a model for your data and parse it in your model.